# Тире после придаточного - помогите понять, к чему относится

Tags: недопустимая-метка

> Повторное празднество, на этот раз понимая, что, как и его
>   предшественник, он не доживёт до того момента, о котором мечтал
>   покровитель Бернини – увидеть из окна своей резиденции сверкающий
>   каррарский мрамор в струях воды, устроил для себя Бенедикт XIV
>   (1740–1758).

Закрыть придаточное запятой?

Очень тяжёлое предложение? Или ничего?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему нельзя использовать скобки для обособления вставной конструкции?

Повторное празднество, на этот раз понимая, как и его предшественник, что  он не доживёт до того момента, о котором мечтал покровитель Бернини (увидеть из окна своей резиденции сверкающий каррарский мрамор в струях воды), устроил для себя Бенедикт XIV (1740–1758).

Comment: Щас автора утешу! Спасибо!

Comment: А последовательность слов как будет воспринята?.. "Повторное празднество, на этот раз понимая, как и его предшественник, что он не доживёт..."

Comment: С последовательностью это я накреативила, смысл меняется, пусть уж авторская остаётся.

Answer (score 2):

Да, не просто тяжелое, - громоздкое!
Главное здесь, насколько я понимаю: *Повторное празднество...устроил для себя Бенедикт XIV (1740–1758).*

Тогда попроще для восприятия, мне кажется, "смотрится" такой вариант:
***Повторное празднество - на этот раз понимая, что, как и его предшественник, он не доживёт до того момента, о котором мечтал покровитель Бернини: увидеть из окна своей резиденции сверкающий каррарский мрамор в струях воды, - устроил для себя Бенедикт XIV (1740–1758).***